# How to manage arbitrary arguments in a C function

Tags: c, arrays, function

Suppose I have a function with arbitrary argument.
Example :

```
 execl(char *path, char *arg0,...,char *argn, 0)
```

Function definition: [`execl()`](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/OLDC/subsubsection2_18_4_1_1.html#SECTION00184110000000000000)

So no matter how many appropriate arguments (>=3) I have sent to it, it will work. Now say I have a array of string which contains `arg0`, `arg1`, `arg2`, ... `argn`.

How can I call this function with my arbitrary number of string. That means, if I have a array of string size 3 then I want to call a function like this,

```
execl(char *path, char *arg0,char *arg1, char *arg2, 0)
```

and if I have a array of string size 4 then I want to call a function like this

```
execl(char *path, char *arg0,char *arg1, char *arg2,char *arg4, 0)
```

Is there any automatic way to do so. I do not want to use if condition to do something like this...(if I have array size 2 call a two argument function, if I have array size 3 call a three argument function, etc).
Is there any process? Please explain in a short code.

Comment: google on `va_list, va_start, va_end`

Comment: why don't you just pass the array and another argument for the size of the array.  Than deal with said arguments in the function as a for loop or while loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking how to call a function with a variable number of arguments that you build within a single function. The short answer is you can't. While c has variadic function support, it is to receive not to call.  Meaning, you can write a function that accepts a variable number of arguments, but cannot pass them to another https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function

NOTE: I wasn't sure whether your `execl()` code was just meant to demonstrate your question OR you were looking for how to use `exec*()` functions with variable arguments. If it was the latter, check out `execv()` which accepts an array of strings.

Comment: Actually I find the problem while I was making a shell like program. So I include this to my example. Thanks for your generous answer.
And can you give me some resource of execp() function. I search through net and also try 'man execp' but non of them isn't working.